# How i can filter git log on multiple tags

Tags: git, git-tag

After I commit to master I run several CI that tag the commit they finished successfully. Say I have two CI - unit tests and integration tests that both create tags on the commit. Say `unittest-signoff/{number}` and `integrationtest-signoff/{number}`, where *{number}* is autoincremental number to assure uniqueness.

if I execute `git log -n1 --tags="unittest-signoff"` this will give me the most recent commit that is already signed off from unit tests. Same for `git log -n1 --tags="integrationtest-signoff"`

My question is, what command will give me the most recent commit that has both tags at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git log` lets you choose which decorations to look at, so this should serve:

```
git log --no-walk --tags  --pretty=%H\ %d --decorate-refs=refs/tags/*-signoff \
| grep integrationtest-signoff | grep -m1 unittest-signoff
```

Comment: Very clever, +1. I would have used also the `--tags` pattern with something like `--tags="*-signoff/*"`. This one should probably be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I expected git to have something ready for that, but I did not find it. Nonetheless, I still believe I missed it somehow, maybe using some glob pattern I am not aware of? This is an alternative way to do it:

```
git rev-list --all | while read cmt
do
    cmt_tags=""
    while read tag
    do
        cmt_tags+="$(echo "$tag" | awk -F'/' '{ print $1; }') "
    done <<< "$(git tag --points-at "$cmt" "integrationtest-signoff/*" "unittest-signoff/*")"
    
    test "$cmt_tags" = "integrationtest-signoff unittest-signoff " && echo "$cmt" && break
done
```

Assuming you are tagging `master` branch, I basically looped over each commit until I find the commit with both tags. `git tag --points-at` returns all the tags in alphabetical order (this is what I observed), but I do not want the part after `/` so I take only the first token with `awk`.
Thanks to the pattern provided to `git tag` I am sure it returns only those tags matching the pattern, in the end I just compare the `cmt_tags` string with the expected one and `break` as soon as I find a commit.

Not very elegant but simple enough to solve your problem, I would say.

---

@torek proposed an interesting performance enhancement using [`git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref). The first line of the previous script could be replaced with:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(committerdate)|%(objectname)" --sort=-committerdate "refs/tags/integrationtest-signoff/*" "refs/tags/unittest-signoff/*" | sort -u -r | awk -F '|' '{ print $2; }' | while read cmt
```

Now, instead of looping over commits, I only loop over specific-tagged commits. Performances depend on how many commits are tagged with `integrationtest-/unittest-`, of course.

Comment: If the goal of the question is indeed to find a single commit to which two tags point: consider using `git for-each-ref refs/tags/` to get the hash IDs from tags. Use the `--format` directive to get the commit object, rather than the tag object. Then just compare the hash IDs. In a large repository, this will probably be faster as it won't have to traverse as many commit objects. In a small repository it's probably about the same,

Comment: @torek Thank you. I tried with `for-each-ref` with a different approach, now it seems very appropriate. Honestly, I did not even consider the performance issue since the OP explicitly said that he is on a CI environment and I hope he does not have to take a range of hundreds of commits before finding a tested one :) By the way, thank you again, very helpful advice.

Comment: @torek Edited. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Something like that, yes. But instead of feeding that to more shell loops, you should be able to just compare the commit hash IDs. I'm thinking maybe use awk's associative arrays (hash maps)...

Comment: Sorry, kept editing the comment. :-) If you run your for-each-ref output through awk, you can map each `integrationtest-signoff` tag commit hash ID, then check the incoming (sorted) `unittest-signoff` hash IDs as you go, or vice versa. I'm not sure if this requires two separate `for-each-ref` invocations.

Comment: @torek seems a little more complex but worth a try. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit: I may have misread the question.  See [Marco Luzzara's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67237949/1256452) to find a way to see the answer to a different interpretation.]

Consider the `--no-walk` flag to `git log`, e.g., `git log --no-walk tag1 tag2`.

#### Wait, I was using `-n 1`, isn't that the same thing?

No.  There is a world of difference between `--no-walk` and `-n 1`.  The `-n` argument to `git log` tells it to *quit entirely* after printing some number of revisions.  With `-n 1`, `git log` quits as soon as it shows one particular commit.

The *way `git log` works* is the key here.  When you run:

```
git log [options] starting-point-1 starting-point-2 starting-point-3
```

the `git log` command inserts the three selected starting point commits into a *queue* (specifically a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue), though we won't worry about the priority part here).  Try running `git rev-parse` on a name (branch name, remote-tracking name, or tag name for instance):

```
$ git rev-parse origin/maint
48bf2fa8bad054d66bd79c6ba903c89c704201f7
$ git rev-parse v2.23.0
cb715685942260375e1eb8153b0768a376e4ece7
```

These hash IDs—the second one is actually a *tag* hash ID, rather than a *commit* hash ID, but `git log` knows what to do with it—can act as "starting points" for `git log`.  Or, given *no* starting point, `git log` uses `git rev-parse HEAD`, or the equivalent, to find the commit hash ID to insert into this queue, so that the queue has just *one* commit in it.  If you give `git log` *one* commit specifier, that's the one commit that goes into the queue.

Once the queue is primed—by your command line starting points, or by `git log` using `HEAD`—the real work begins.

#### The real work of `git log`, which is run as a loop, over and over

At this point `git log` starts by taking *one* commit *out* of the queue.  If there was just the one commit *in* the queue, the queue is now empty.  If the queue was *already* empty, `git log` quits now, as there's nothing to take out.

Having taken a commit out of the queue, `git log` now fishes the commit out of the big database that Git keeps all the commits in.  It examines the commit.  If you gave `git log` options, these options may decide whether or not to *print* the commit.  If you gave *no* options, `git log` is supposed to print the commit now.

**If** `git log` is supposed to print the commit, `git log` prints the commit now.  If there's a `-n` limit, this decrements the remaining count, and when it's gone to zero, `git log` quits immediately.  Without `-n`, or if the count is big enough, we keep going.

**In any case** `git log` now has the *option* to put the commit's *parent commit(s) into the queue*.  This option is the default.  An *ordinary* commit has exactly one parent, so for most commits, this puts the one parent into the queue.  A *merge* commit has two or more parents—usually just two—so for merge commits, this puts all the parents into the queue.

This completes the real work.  We now go back to the loop, so as to continue working with the queue.

#### In most cases this produces just what you're used to seeing

Suppose we have a nice simple linear string of commits, ending at the *current commit*—i.e., `HEAD`—on the *current branch*, like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

Running `git log` with no arguments has Git figure out which commit is the *current* one, which is commit `H`.  The queue has one commit in it.

The log program now extracts the one commit from the queue, which goes empty.  That's commit `H`.  It prints the contents of commit `H` and puts `H`'s parent, `G`, into the queue.  The queue now has one commit in it.

The log program now extracts the one commit from the queue, which goes empty.  That's commit `G` this time, so `git log` prints the contents of `G` and puts `G`'s parent, `F`, into the queue.

This repeats for `F`, which leads back to another commit, which `git log` prints, and so on—all the way down the line to the *very first* commit, which has *no* parents.  At that point `git log` runs out of queue and stops.

#### The `--no-walk` option, part 1

With `--no-walk`, we instruct `git log`, in its *deal with the commit off the queue* step, to put *no parents into the queue*.  If we use this with our bog-standard `git log` with the current branch being `main` and the current commit being commit `H`, what happens is straightforward:

- `git log` puts `HEAD`, i.e., `H`, into the queue;
- `git log` pops `H` off the queue;
- `git log` prints commit `H` and puts nothing into the queue;
- and the queue is now empty and `git log` quits.

#### Comparing to the `-n 1` option, part 1

With `-n 1` and one starting point and no restrictions on what gets printed:

- `git log` puts `HEAD`, i.e., `H`, into the queue;
- `git log` pops `H` off the queue;
- `git log` prints commit `H` and puts its parent `G` into the queue, but has printed one commit, so it quits.

The output here is *the same*.

#### Compare with, e.g., `git log --no-walk HEAD HEAD~2`

Here we've given `git log` *two* commits to put in the queue: `HEAD` or `H`, and `HEAD~2` or `F`.

- `git log` pops one of the commits—probably `H`—off the queue;
- `git log` prints this one commit, but adds no parents;
- `git log` pops the remaining commit—probably `F`—off the queue;
- `git log` prints this commit, but again adds no parents;

and the queue is now empty so we print these two commits and quit.

#### Would using `-n 2` work?

Try it with `HEAD HEAD~2`.  We start with `H` and `F` in the queue.  Let's further assume that the queue order is such that the *newest* commit is always printed first (this is the default).  So:

- `git log` pops `H` off the queue, and prints it, and puts `G` on the queue;
- `git log` pops `G` off the queue—it's the newest, compared to `F`—and prints it;

and those are the two commits it is allowed to print, so it now exits.  It never printed commit `F` at all!

#### Conclusion: `--no-walk` is the flag for this purpose

If you want `git log` to print *only the commits you specify on the command line*, well, that's exactly what `--no-walk` is for.  Use it for its designed purpose, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with to do this in pure bash:

```
comm -12 <(git log --no-walk --tags=unittest-signoff --format="format:%H %ct"|sort) <(git log --no-walk --tags=integrationtest-signoff --format="format:%H %ct"|sort) | sort -k 2 -r | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

To break it down:

```
git log --no-walk --tags=unittest-signoff --format="format:%H %ct"
```

prints the hashes with their commit timestamp. `sort` because `comm` needs sorted input. After `comm` finds the common hashes between the two tag sets, `sort` them again according to the timestamp, and finally `head` and `cut` to get the most recent commit from both tag sets.

[Edit] still need `--no-walk`

Comment: Not working in my demo. It returns a commit tagged with `integrationtest-*` only.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara would it be possible to reproduce your demo in a few steps? I'm curious where it broke down. But I agree with you that jthill's solution is the best one by far.

Comment: Sure, I think you just have to create 4 commits, from the most recent: 1- tag with unittest. 2- tag with integration test. 3 and 4- tag with both unit and integration test. If it does not work, try adding new commits and new tags (even not unit and integration test). I already had a slightly more complex repo that I tagged for this question. If you cannot reproduce my issue with your solution I can share my repo with you in case.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara got it.  Managed to forget about `--no-walk` despite torek highlighting it...   Thanks.